# Interrupts in relation to the OS and CPU

Tags: interrupt

In my lecture slides it says that an interrupt gets the attention of the CPU, but when I am reading online articles it says that interrupts get the attention of the OS. Can someone explain to me why there is a difference in text? Does the interrupt go to the OS first and then the OS contacts the CPU? I am quite confused here because initially I thought interrupts directly get the attention of the CPU, but it seems that it gets the attention of the OS first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This post is about x86 only. Interrupts may work differently in other architectures.*

There are two kinds of interrupts: hardware interrupts and software interrupts. Hardware interrupts are generated by hardware on your system: for example, the timer, devices (e.g., keyboard input), etc. Software interrupts are generated by code via the `int` instruction.

In both cases, your operating system kernel has to install *interrupt handlers* that get called when an interrupt is triggered. An interrupt handler for the timer might cause the kernel to task-switch. A software interrupt would usually be for making system calls, as an entry point for user-level code to request functionality from the kernel (e.g., to open a file or read from a file descriptor); interrupts 0x21 (for DOS) and 0x80 (for Unix) are examples of system-call software interrupts.

To answer the question, a hardware interrupt would get the attention of the CPU, so to speak, but ultimately the OS kernel has to know what to do with it too, by installing a useful interrupt handler.